# ¿Por qué no me deja usar @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Me marca error en el `@Autowired` que tengo en el método guardar datos de la clase DatosUsuarioController y no se por qué, en las otras clases no tengo ningún problema.

```java
public class DatosUsuarioController{

    public DatosUsuarioController(){}


    @FXML
    private Button guardarBut;
    @FXML
    private Button cancelarBut;
    @FXML
    private TextField nombreID;
    @FXML
    private TextField telefonoID;
    @FXML
    private TextField direccionID;
    @FXML
    private Label textoSup;

    Stage stage;


    public void usuarioRegister(ActionEvent actionEvent){;
        guardarDatos();
    }

    public void cerrarVentana(ActionEvent event){
        exitWindow();
    }


    private void exitWindow(){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Salir");
        alert.setHeaderText("¿Estás seguro que quieres salir?");
        if (alert.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK){

            stage = (Stage) cancelarBut.getScene().getWindow();
            System.out.println("Has salido exitosamente.");
            stage.close();
        }
    }

    private void guardarDatos(){
        String nombre = nombreID.getText();
        String telefono = telefonoID.getText();
        String direccion = direccionID.getText();
        Long tel= Long.parseLong(telefono);
        if ((nombre.isEmpty() || telefono.isEmpty() || direccion.isEmpty())){
            textoSup.setText("Datos incompletos, por favor ingréselos");
        }
        else {
            textoSup.setText("Datos guardados exitosamente!");

            stage = (Stage) guardarBut.getScene().getWindow();

            System.out.println("Has salido exitosamente. Tus datos fueron registrados.");
            stage.close();
        }
        @Autowired// Me marca error en este @Autowired y no entiendo porque
        PersonaService personaService;

        personaService.agregarCliente(nombre,direccion,tel);
        //cuando ande instanciaria cliente service y usaria el metodo agregarCliente
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

La anotación `@Autowired` sólo se puede usar sobre atributos (propiedades) de un objeto. En este caso estás intentando que se inyecte en una variable local de un método, lo que no es posible. La solución es declarar el servicio como atributo:

```java
public class DatosUsuarioController{

    public DatosUsuarioController(){}

    @Autowired
    PersonaService personaService;

    // resto de código
}
```